# How can entanglement entropy be quantified between lattices of differing structures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, ising-model, information

Suppose there are two 1 dimensional particle lattices, both with differing distances between particles and not necessarily the same number of particles. Each particle exists in a superposition of spin up and spin down with known probabilities (i.e. alpha and beta are known). Adjacent particles interact with one another depending on how far away they are from one another.

How can the degree of entanglement be quantified using von Neumann entropy *while taking into account the distances between the particles*?

Comment: Why do you think the distance between particles should be taken into account?

Comment: @mbintz Is it not necessary? Is it that interactions between the particles are not necessary to consider because that information is already found in the probability of their being in the up or down spin state? Also, I thought the wave function takes into account position, so wouldn't that information be necessary?

Comment: The question is confusing. Could you provide a Hamiltonian of your system? Also, "distance between particles" sounds quite classical. Do you mean the distance between the mean average of the (one-body?) probability distributions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.